# Interpreting functions for poset

Tags: order-theory, lattice-orders

I'm stuck at a question with the following expression of poset $(\mathcal{N}, \sqsubseteq)$:
$$\forall x, y \in \mathcal{N}: x \sqsubseteq y \mbox{ iff } (x = y \vee x = \bot_{\mathcal{N}} \vee y = \top_{\mathcal{N}}).$$

$\mathcal{N} = \mathcal{N} \bigcup\{ \bot_{\mathcal{N}} , \top_{\mathcal{N}}  \} $ consists of all natural numbers with two elements $ \bot_{\mathcal{N}} $ and $ \top_{\mathcal{N}} $, and I'll need to find the poset height.

I don't know how to interpret this expression though.

Comment: Would you care to explain what all the notation represents? Also, what is your specific question?

Comment: @A.P. I'm not sure how to interpret the expression. After which I'll need to find the poset height.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This poset is the set of all natural numbers with equality relation, so any two distinct elements $x, y \in \mathcal{N}$ are incomparable, together with the least $\bot_\mathcal{N}$ and the greatest $\top_\mathcal{N}$ elements. To find its height you should find the largest cardinality chain, that is a subset in which any two elements are comparable. Can you take it from there?

**Hint:** Since any two distinct $x, y \in \mathcal{N}$ are incomparable, every chain in this poset can contain at most one element from $\mathcal{N}$. You can start by trying to find the chains of cardinality $1, 2$ and so on. It can be useful to draw a Hasse diagram for this poset.

*Updated.* Here is some definitions (which you are assumed to be familiar with given that problem). Let $(P, \sqsubseteq)$ be a poset. Two elements $x, y \in P$ are *comparable* if either $x \sqsubseteq y$ or $y \sqsubseteq x$.
A *chain* $C$ is a subset of $P$ such that any two elements $x, y \in C$ are comparable. The *height* of $P$ is the largest cardinality (or size) of a chain in $P$.

So roughly, to find the height of your poset you should check all chains in it and find the chains of the largest size. Note the following:

1. If $C$ is a chain, then $C \cup \{\top_\mathcal{N}\}$ and $C \cup \{\bot_\mathcal{N}\}$ are also chains. This is because the least and the greatest elements are comparable with any element of a poset.
2. If $x, y \in \mathcal{N}$ and they are both not equal to $\top_\mathcal{N}$ and $\bot_\mathcal{N}$, then by definition of $\sqsubseteq$ we have $x \sqsubseteq y$ if and only if $x = y$.

From 1 it follows that if you have some chain, you can always add the least and the greatest elements to it obtaining new (and in general larger) chain. From 2 it follows that any chain in your poset can't contain two distinct natural numbers from $\mathcal{N}$ since they are not comparable. It means that the chain of maximal cardinality has at most $3$ element: $\top_\mathcal{N}$, $\bot_\mathcal{N}$ and some natural number $x \in \mathcal{N}$. And obviously there are such chains in your poset. So its height is $3$.

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm sure this is useful, but this is my first week into this lecture topic, so I'm still having difficulty understanding the cardinality and 'at most one element from N'. Are there multiple Ns or cardinalities? Maybe you could expand a little on your answer for a layman, please?

Comment: @George: Which of the following notions you are familiar with: poset, comparable elements, chain, hieght of a poset, the least and the greatest elements? [Cardinality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality) is a characteristic of sets (it is not directly related to posets).

Comment: If you refer to notations and not sets of notations, then I do know briefly: poset, least & greatest elements.